# Create new table in SQL with calculated values

Tags: sql, alter-table

If I have a table with a few columns in MySQL and want to create a *permanent* column that is the sum of two other columns (kind of like an alter table statement with preset values for each row), how do I do it?

E.g.

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
1, 21, 41
4, 81, 12
```

And I want column D that is the sum of columns A and B and is permanent. I know I can run a query that is just 'Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnA+ColumnB AS ColumnD From MyTable' but that won't make column D a permanent part of the table.

Comment: You can use a trigger to catch inserts/updates and re-calculate/update the appropriate column values. Generally speaking, though, it's usually bad form to have a column which simply contains derived data from other columns in the same record. The only time it's permissible is if the calculations necessary are too "expensive" to perform on the fly. For a simple `D = A + B`, it's trivial and not really worth doing.

Comment: @MarcB Okay, but I want to do more complex things than that and I was just giving that as a simple example. I don't really know how to do what you described in your first sentence either.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a view like below. Well, it will not store the data unless you are making it as parametrized view and essentialy every time you say `select * from myview` it will fire the select against base table but still an valid option.

```
create view myview
as
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnA+ColumnB AS ColumnD From MyTable
```

Otherwise, you can go for maintaining a separate table altogether like below.

```
create table derivedtable
as
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnA+ColumnB AS ColumnD From MyTable
```

OR, have `columnD int null` in your table and create a `after insert` trigger and populate that column like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_calc` 
AFTER INSERT ON `MyTable` 
FOR EACH ROW  
    UPDATE `MyTable` SET `ColumnD` = ColumnA+ColumnB 
WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

Assuming that, your table has a unique id column.

Comment: That works well but it is a little cumbersome if I only want to add one column. Thanks though.

Comment: @user3081195, see my updated answer.I have provided the option to go with trigger with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in mysql. If you really want the column a trigger would be your best bet.

Just adding some expressions in your query would likely also be fine. Remember that the DBMS often spends most of its time waiting for the disk to deliver more records to chew up. If processing those records takes somewhat longer, you may not see any added time in your query. In essence, the DBMS would have just been sleeping or busy waiting if it didn't have more work to do.

Finally, if there is a real need to do the computations in advance, and you want something easier to use than a couple triggers, you can switch DB vendors:

- SQL Server has computed columns: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx
- Oracle has virtual columns: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-schemamanagement-089869.html
- Postgres is halfway there with indexes on expressions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html

wiki article for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column